# Mandar alerta de finalización cuando se termina de ejecutar un <form> de HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Hola estoy generando un sistema de nóminas, en un punto en concreto utilizo este formulario para procesar una nomina

```
    <form class="form-login" action="procedimientos_funciones/sp_GeneraNomNor.php" method="post">
        <p>Clave de nómina</p>
        <input class="controls" type="text" name="CveNomina" value="" required>
        <p>Fecha de inicio de nómina</p>
        <input class="controls" type="date" name="Del" required>
        <p>Fecha de fin de nómina</p>
        <input class="controls" type="date" name="Al" required>
        <p>Honorarios</p>
        <input class="controls" type="text" name="GenHon" required>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input class="buttons" type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Enviar información">
        <br>
        <input class="buttons" type="reset" name="" value="Vaciar campos">
        
    </form>
```

Como se puede observar envio los datos por POST mediante un accion, el respectivo codigo es el siguiente

```
<?php
/*Realizando conexion a la BD*/
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "SiscopevW2");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Falló la conexión con MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ")" . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$CveNomina = $_POST['CveNomina'];
$Del = $_POST['Del'];
$Al = $_POST['Al'];
$GenHon = $_POST['GenHon'];


if ($GenHon == 1) {
    $mysqli->query("TRUNCATE TABLE DetNomina");
    $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM Nominas");
    $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM tmpDetNomina");
} else {
    $mysqli->query("CALL sp_GeneraNomNor ('$CveNomina','$Del','$Al','$GenHon')");
}
?>
<?php
header("location: ../procesar_Nomina.php");
?>
```

Podría parecer poco pero se ejecuta un procedimiento almacenado en la base de datos el cual tarda hasta 30 segundos en completarse ya que es bastante extenso, por lo que me gustaría mandar una alerta cuando el proceso acabe de ejecutarse, he intentado usar `alert` de JavaScript, pero no funciona

De antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución es cambiar el **header** por un [meta refresh](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/meta-refresh/) de este modo:

```php
echo '<script>
alert("Proceso terminado")
</script>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=../procesar_Nomina.php" />';
```

Prueba y nos cuentas.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias eres un genio, te agradezco demasiado, solo una pegunta cuando sale la alerta se tarda un poco en regresar a la ruta especificada en url=../procesar_Nomina.php", no se tarda mucho como 2 o 3 seg, hay alguna forma de que lo haga de inmediato

Comment: Ya lo logré, solo tuve que reducir el parámetro refresh y se actualiza en automático, nuevamente muchas gracias eres un genio